# PHP - dropdown list content showing href link content without selection

Tags: php, html

I have a variable numbr forms I want a user to be able to choose to view via a  drop down list. I have assigned each of the form content to array $forms & the associated form name to array $formnames

The idea was to display the variable number of form names as buttons in the drop down selection, and once selected it would display the form content.

I've tried the below code but this leads to the drop down selection immediately showing both the form content as well as name. Could someone point me in the right direction given my limited understanding?

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="dropdownfunction()" class="dropbtn">Available List</button>
<div id="avaiablelist" class="dropdown-content">

<?php 
$keys = array_keys($forms);
$namekeys = array_keys($formnames); 
$arraysize = count($forms);

    for($i=0;  $i<$arraysize;$i++) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $forms[$i]['form'];?>"> <?php echo $formnames[$i]['formname']; ?> </a> 
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case i would use

```
<form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> method="post">
</form>
```

to send $forms[$i]['form'] via Post method